# Gameloop wont match css animation

Tags: javascript

(I'm trying to make a basic space invaders game)I'm very new to coding so this might be a total mess, however, I'm using gameloop(s). One of them is moving the hero, one is moving the missiles, and drawing them. However, I can't seem to split them. I want to split them up so I can change the setTimeout, but it doesn't want to split up.

Tried to split them up by making a gameloop_1();, but that wouldn't move the missiles... sooo... I'm lost

```
var missiles = [];

function drawMissiles() {
document.getElementById('missiles').innerHTML = ""
    for (var i = 0; i < missiles.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('missiles').innerHTML += `<div 
class='missile1' style='left:${missiles[i].left}px; 
top:${missiles[i].top}px'></div>`;
    }
}
function moveMissiles() {
    for (var i = 0; i < missiles.length; i++) {
        missiles[i].top = missiles[i].top - 15
    }
}

function gameLoop() {
    setTimeout(gameLoop, 950)
    moveMissiles();
    drawMissiles();
    moveFiende();
    drawFiende();
    collisionDetection();
}

function gameLoop_1() {
    setInterval(gameLoop_1, 100)
    moveMissiles();
    drawMissiles();
}

    gameLoop();
    gameLoop_1();
```

What happens when I split them up, is as I said; The missiles won't then shoot.

Comment: There are a number of issues here. 1) the `setInterval` inside `gameLoop_1` should be `setTimeout`, the way you have it now you'll have millions of calls to `gameLoop_1` inside seconds and likely crash your browser. 2) You don't need `gameLoop_1` at all here, since you're calling the functions within it from `gameLoop` (and there's no reason ever to have more than one game loop, that loop should call all the processes you need) 3) It's better to use `requestAnimationFrame` for things like this than `setTimeout`

Comment: Also cache the DOM element. On page load store `document.getElementById('missiles')` in a var and access that one in the loops

Comment: But gameloop is set to 950, but I want to the missiles to go faster, hence, the gameloop_1. moveMissiles(); and drawMissiles(); was made into comments, so they don't interferere with eachother.

Comment: There's nothing commented out in the snippet you've got in your post. Anyway, have you tried anything I suggested in my first comment? As I said, the biggest issue I can see is that by having `setInterval(gameLoop_1, 100)` inside `gameLoop_1` will generate ever-faster repeated calls to `gameLoop_1`, which I would expect to crash the browser tab within a matter of seconds.

Comment: Yes, I tried that and worked really well. One question on requestAnimationFrame though. How do I choose the speed of it?

Comment: @Ben - you can't. The whole idea is that it updates once every frame. If you need to control the timing of things in your game then you can use counter variables to only call certain functions every nth frame.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Ah I'll give that a shot, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:**
If you expect an answer for your specific code here, you'll be disappointed, so if you do not intend to start from scratch or something like that, I'm sorry for the whole text.

---

I think you're misundertanding the purpose of a Game Loop.

There are some things wrong with your code, but I'll stick with the basis of your question, which also happen to be the basis of every game, the Game Loop.

## Frames

Let's start with Frames. You probably know what a Frame is. It is like a drawing on the screen of a single moment in time. For example, when you watch a movie, you're actually watching a lot of pictures (frames) being drawn very fast, one after another, which gives the illusion of movement (usually 30 "pictures" per second).

## The Game Loop

The Game Loop is the responsible for drawing the frames of the game, one after another, it executes functions, methods, changes variables and based on the results, it finally draws on the screen what is happening on the game.

The Game loop is basically what makes everything in the game possible to happen, it's like what *time* is for us in real life: without time passing, there would be no past, present or future, we would be stuck in a single frame forever.
The same happens on a game, withou a Game Loop, there would be no iterations, nor changes or frame updates.

## Extremely basic game structure

Knowing that, the first thing you must do is always having a "central" game loop, and never split it. Always name other methods as "updates" and call them from the master game loop.
So a most correct structure for your code would be (this is just pseudocode similar to js, not any language in particular):

```
SpaceInvaders = {
  GameLoop(){
    UpdatePlayer();
    UpdateProjectile();
    UpdateEnemies();

    setTimeout(GameLoop, 16) // to call the loop each 16ms, thus giving you 60fps
  }

  UpdatePlayer(){
    // do stuff like move the player and fire
  }

  UpdateProjectile(){
    // do stuff like move the projectile and check if it hitted something
  }

  UpdateEnemies(){
    // do stuff like move the enemies
  }
}


SpaceInvaders.GameLoop();
```

If you want to have a more in depth look on Game Loops, please check this amazing article, it helped me a lot when I was starting my first HTML5 canvas game:
https://isaacsukin.com/news/2015/01/detailed-explanation-javascript-game-loops-and-timing

You'll be presented with the hardware compensation problem that comes as consequence of the Game Loop and some other interesting stuff.

## Your situation

Now that the Game Loop principle is better explained, let's talk about your specific situation a little more. There are 3 main things that pop into my eye:

First of all, I don't think that it is going to be a good experience to try making a game using only HTML concatenation and CSS, if you really want to do it from scratch all by yourself, I hardly encourage you to try making a game using **HTML5 canvas**. For me it was a great experience to learn the very basics of game development. As I look back now, tho, I see how my code sucks (used vanilla js, and compensated the hardware by hand on each frame in all moving entities). If you want to see this project done:
https://github.com/diguifi/littlejsworld

Second, you're not working with objects, that's going to make the code very messy in later stages of development and very hard to work with (even if it's just space invaders). What I mean by objectifying your game is, for example: instead of loose methods for "drawMissiles" and "moveMissiles" you should have an object called "Missile" and another called "Player".
The Missiles would have such methods ("draw" and "move", accesible via "Missile.draw()") and the Player would have a list of Missiles (this is just an example, you must use objects for everything in your game, in order to have a well designed project).

And third, seems to me that concatenating divs on *innerHtml* of an element from the DOM is not a good thing to do, it's very costly, ugly and time consuming.

## My suggestions

If you want to make this game as an exercice for learning the basis of game development, I think you should start from scratch using only a canvas element and center your code efforts on the javascript, not messing with html elements to create the game. There are many articles and docs to help you in this task, such as the one I mentioned that talks about game loop.

If your goal is just to make a game, without having to understand basic problems, you should try a game engine, such as:

- Godot: a free, easy and lightweight engine to create games, no need to worry about game loop here.
- Phaser: code with js, without worrying about game loop management and many other basic stuff.
- Unity: code in C# but not so much code is needed
- Game Maker Studio: no coding needed, only basic programming logic
- Construct 3: same as Game Maker, maybe easier

Comment: Please note that, while outdated, Construct 2 is still a pretty neat engine and you don't have to subscribe to a software as a service contract to use it.
It's pretty amazing to get started on game development since it's super easy but follows the same principles as more advanced engines.

Comment: In your code `setInterval()` function call is inside of `GameLoop`, so it will make recursively a lot of loops!

Comment: @DiegoPenha Hello, sorry for the late responds. Thanks for the input, it helped a lot.